# Browser not updating scrollbar after inserting html

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, scrollbar

I'm using a specific template which seems to cause a deffect with scrolling.
Whenever I recieve data from ajax and insert enough HTML so that the page *should* get a vertical scrollbar, it doesn't.

When I open up chrome devtools, or when I hover an element that has a popover, the scrollbar suddenly appears.

It only seems to effect google chrome.

I can't seem to find the cause and I'm wondering if there is something I can do to trigger an update, just like the devtools do.

Comment: Any chance you have an example up and running for us to check out?

Comment: nope sorry, its in a ip protected area of the company i'm making it for at the moment

Comment: Are you running the latest version of Google Chrome?

Comment: yes I am running the latest version

Comment: Very strange. Without some sort of proof of concept, I don't think I can think of anything else you could try...

Comment: will try to setup an example page. tnx for the help

Comment: @Flion Are you using some Plugin for scrollbars ? If yes, you need to look into reinitialize the scrollbar plugin

Answer (score 0):

When using jQuery, you could try to do

```
$(window).trigger('resize');
```

To trigger a resize, like what happens when you open your devtools.

Comment: yes, just tried that, doesn't work. yet when I do resize the window the scrollbars emediatly appear